# how to fix size of the output window via assembly x86 for windows

Tags: assembly, resize, x86, window, output

I am writing a program via assembly x86 language . for this reason I used emu8086 program.
I decided to fix the size of output window in 85*25 character (25row * 80column) , I want to take the ability of the  re-size of the window  (the window can not change to big or small)
please share your useful ideas.

Comment: My useful idea is that if you want to write code to a modern OS (Linux or Windows), don't do it using tools meant for running legacy code. Learn 64-bit x86-64 or 32-bit x86 assembly language for the target OS (Linux or Windows, I assume).

Answer (score 0):

emu8086 does not only simulate a 8086 CPU but it also simulates hardware (e.g. a VGA card).

The simulated VGA card is running in text mode. VGA cards however can only display some given number of screen resolutions (e.g. 80x25, 40x25, ...). Some VGA cards allow 132x44 but this mode is not standard and therefore it is probably not supported by emu8086.

The standard VGA cards allow modes like 80x50 but using this mode ...

- ... the size of each character is half as high so the size of the window in pixels is the same as for 80x25
- ... initializing this mode is quite tricky and needs a lot of code

If you really want to resize the console window (maybe to 100x50 characters) you cannot use emu8086 that easiely.

You could hook the screen and console interrupts (10h, 16h, some functions of 21h and if mouse is required 33h) and include some virtual hardware device and use a Windows console window... However this attempt requires a lot of programming work and excellent assembler and C knowledge!